# Google Analytics Filter does not show old data. Only useful going forward?

Tags: google-analytics, seo, subdirectory

I have setup a custom view with a filter to include only one particular subdirectory.

The site has been around for years but the new view only shows data from the point of creation and onward.

Is there a way to include all (past/present/future) traffic for the subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters only take effect moving forward (from when they are first implemented) and cannot affect past data. In general, it is best practice to set up your GA account with the following views:

1. Raw - all your data unfiltered
2. Test - a view to test filters, etc.
3. Master - for reporting to your managers, etc.

Once a filter has been applied to data, it cannot be undone, even if you have removed the filter at a later time, that is why it is best to test filters in your Test view first.

Comment: whats the difference between Raw and Master? I used copy view (of my main view) to apply the filter to. Im assuming that will not affect my main view.

Comment: Raw would contain all your data unfiltered. Master would be filtered and have good data - data that you would use for reporting.

Comment: unfortunate that filters only work one way but seems to be the way it is.